# how to bind array to nested field with Jquery in ASp.NET mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `ViewModel` Like this :

```
public class SaveWorkOrderViewModel
{
    public Guid WorkOrderId { get; set; }
    public List<SaveWorkOrderDelayReasonViewModel> DelayReasons { get; set; }
}
public class SaveWorkOrderDelayReasonViewModel
{
    public Guid DelayReasonId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and I have `controller` that get `SaveWorkOrderViewModel` as param Like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult Save(SaveWorkOrderViewModel saveWorkOrderViewModel)
{
    ....
}
```

to `bind` data to this I tried like this :

```
var workOrderId = $(this).data('workOrderId'); // return guid
var DelayReasons = $("#drpdelay").select2("val"); // return array of guid
var saveWorkOrderViewModel = {
    workOrderId: workorderId,
    DelayReasons: {
        DelayReasonId:DelayReasons 
    }
};
```

but when Post Page , I getting `null` for `DelayReasons`.

I couldn't find any similar post to solve this .

**updated :**

My script for send ajax call is :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.WorkOrder.Save())',
    data: { saveWorkOrderViewModel },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        showMessage(data.message, data.notificationType);
        if (data.result) {
            RefreshKendoGrid('woGrid');
        }
    },
    error: function (response) { }
});
```

Finally I changed scrips like this and its work fine :

```
var fields = [];
$(delays).each(function (index, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["DelayReasonId"] = value;
    obj["Title"] = null;
    fields.push(obj);
});

var saveWorkOrderViewModel = {
    workOrderId: workorderId,
    DelayReasons: fields
};
```

Comment: Are you submitting this using ajax? If so, show your code for the script. And `SaveWorkOrderDelayReasonViewModel` contains a property `Title`. Are you not submitting that?

Comment: yes I use ajax . not I dont fill `Title` field .

Comment: The show your code :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  updated

Comment: Not quite sure why you claiming _and its work fine_. You will get a collection of `SaveWorkOrderDelayReasonViewModel` buttThe values of `DelayReasonId` will not be bound :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `contentType` option to use json, and stringify your data

```
....
var saveWorkOrderViewModel = {
    workOrderId: workorderId,
    DelayReasons: fields
};

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.WorkOrder.Save())',
   data: JSON.stringify(saveWorkOrderViewModel),
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
   success: function (data) {
       ....
```

Alternatively, to use your current ajax options which uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` for `contentType`, you would need to generate the name/value pairs for the collection with indexers, for example (where `xxxx` are your `Guid` values)

```
var saveWorkOrderViewModel = {
    workOrderId: workorderId,
    DelayReasons[0].DelayReasonId: xxxx,
    DelayReasons[1].DelayReasonId: xxxx,
    ....
};
```